# Fatou's Lemma Proof Misunderstanding

Tags: real-analysis

I am missing something fairly basic in the proof for Fatou's lemma.

## Statement

Suppose $<f_n>$ is a sequence of non-negative measurable functions, such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere. Then

$$\int f \leq \underline{\lim} \int f_n$$

## Proof

Suppose as above. Further, let $h$ be a bounded measurable function which is not greater than $f$ and which vanishes outside a set $E'$ of finite measure. Define

$$h_n = \min\{h,f_n\}$$

for each $x$. Then

$$\int_E h = \int_{E'} h = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E'} h_n \leq \underline{\lim} \int f_n$$

Taking the supremum over $h$ gives the result.

## Question

I do not see how taking the supremum over $h$ gives the result. Do they mean $h$ as a function or $h$ over $x$?

Comment: What is $f$ in your statement?

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$

Comment: Tell us what $f$ is in the statement

Comment: They mean over bounded measurable functions $h$.